# How to parse nested JSON arrays from object returned via Moya.Response query

Tags: json, swift, parsing, codable, moya

I am trying to parse a JSON object that I have as a result from my network session (done through MoyaProvider). The returned JSON object has nested JSON arrays in it. It looks something like this:

> Edit: Link to the json file is here. [results.json](https://github.com/jeanathegreat/Appetiser/blob/master/Results.json)

```
{
“resultCount” : 50,
“results” :
[
    {
        “data1”: 1
        “data2”: 2
    },
    {
        “data1”: 1
        “data2”: 2
    },
    {
        “data1”: 1
        “data2”: 2
    }
]
}
```

Now using Moya, I could get the data by using Moya.Response API like this:

```
let jsonObj = try response.mapJSON()
```

But I don't want to do that I want to map it to my Model struct. I have done something like this below. Which I have checked (through OPTION + MouseHover) that objMovie is of type [Movie]

```
let objMovie = try response.map(ITunesSearchResults<Movie>.self).results
```

I have followed a tutorial online using similar technique but I d
don't understand why objMovie does not contain the return values from after executing the line above. I tried to do a

```
print(obj.< propertyofMovie >)
```

but nothing is showing on the console.

**So what gives?**

Here are some code snippets.
Where ITunesSearchResults is:

```
struct ITunesSearchResults<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let results: [T]
}
```

And my Movie structure is this. It conforms to the key values found in the JSON nested array properties.

```
struct Movie: Codable
{
   let trackId: Int
   let trackName: String
   let trackGenre: String
   let trackPrice: Int?
   let longDescription: String

   init(trackId: Int, trackName: String, trackGenre: String, 
   trackPrice: 
   Int?, /*trackImage: Thumbnail,*/ longDescription: String)
   {
    self.trackId = trackId
    self.trackName = trackName
    self.trackGenre = trackGenre
    self.trackPrice = trackPrice ?? 0
    self.longDescription = longDescription
    //self.trackImage = trackImage //TODO: thumbnail: mapp url from json
   }

  private enum MovieCodingKeys: String, CodingKey
  {
    case trackId
    case trackName
    case trackGenre = "primaryGenreName"
    case trackPrice
    //case trackImage
    case longDescription
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
  {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: MovieCodingKeys.self)

    trackId = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .trackId)
    trackName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .trackName)
    trackGenre = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .trackGenre)
    trackPrice = try container.decode(Int?.self, forKey: .trackPrice)
    longDescription = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .longDescription)
  }
}
```

Comment: try https://app.quicktype.io/ for parsing json

Comment: Edited to contain results.json file from hyperlink

Comment: @Doc that tool is quite helpful! However, I have problems using JSONDecoder().decode() method because I get my jsonObj as type Any using response.mapJSON() method provided by Moya. I could not force cast jsonObj of type Any to type Data, which is the data type accepted by 2nd parameter of mentioned method. The error I get is "could not cast value of type NSDictionary to NSString". Is there a correct way of doing this?

Comment: You should get response as `Data` type using the property `response.data`, https://github.com/Moya/Moya/blob/master/Sources/Moya/Response.swift , **can you confirm if** `response.data` **is not available?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use the `Data` response of `Moya` as you **do** want to decode the JSON with `Decodable` for example

```
let data = response.data
```

Your `Movie` struct is too complicated, explicit `CodingKeys` and an `init` method is not needed at all, you get them for free. This is sufficient:

```
struct ITunesSearchResults<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let results: [T]
}

struct Movie: Decodable
{
    let trackId: Int
    let trackName: String
    let trackGenre: String?
    let trackPrice: Double?
    let longDescription: String
}
```

Note that `trackPrice` is `Double` and `trackGenre` and `trackPrice` are optional.

Now decode simply

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(ITunesSearchResults<Movie>.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch { print(error) }
```

---

Note:

**Never** use a syntax like

```
try container.decode(Int?.self, forKey: .trackPrice)
```

There is `decodeIfPresent`

```
try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .trackPrice)
```

The huge benefit is it throws an error if the key is present but the type is wrong like in this concrete case.

Comment: But aren't implementing the `CodingKey` needed to map correct JSON key values to my struct. For example `trackGenre` is named differently in the JSON object. There it is `primareGenreName`

Comment: Your code above has actually printed some data which means this `result` object is not NULL. BUT, why is there no need to append .results to the decoder line? Since I am looking to obtain a `[Movie]` object and this returns a `ITunesSearchResults<Movie>.self` object (but at least this one is not an empty one!)

Comment: OK, it you want to rename keys you have to specify the CodingKeys (but not the `init` method). You get the `Movie` array with `result.results`

Comment: Thank you. The note is helpful. But still I am confused with when the `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws { }` should be implemented/used? Any sample use cases?

Comment: `init(from` should only be implemented if you need a **custom** behavior for example to consider two different types for the same key. Simply: If the JSON can be decoded properly with the synthesized `init` method, don't provide your own.

Comment: Ok. And what is the significance for changing `Codable` to `Decodable`?

Comment: First of all your generic function constrains also only to `Decodable` and as long as you are only **reading** the data `Decodable` is sufficient. `Codable` is `Encodable&Decodable`.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much.